# Deciding whether to use a inner Parallel.For or Task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

i am working on an application that basically takes raw sql, executes it, exports it to a certain format, and compresses it and publishes it to a file share.

since each report is a separate and unrelated to the next and the server machine hosting the application will have enough horsepower, i want to take advantage of the Task library. I was thinking of using the Parallel.For to enumerate through my collection of report requests so they can potentially be handled on separate threads:

```
            Parallel.ForEach(DataAccessFactory().GetPendingReportRequests(), req =>
            {
                ILogger log = Log.ForContext("Report ID", req.Id);
                try
                {
                    log.Information("Starting Work");
                    new ReportWorker(DataAccessFactory(), ZipPackageFactory(), FileSystemFactory()).Run(req);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.Error(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    log.Information("Ending Work");
                }
            }
        );
```

one of the last processing steps that happen within the ReportWorker class is exporting the data to excel (or csv), compressing each zip file, and finally copying the file(s) to a remove share (on the cloud). this can be a length process and I was wondering if i should use another Parallel.For here (for each file) or use a Task. I am not very familiar with using the Task object quite yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Might be a bit of topic but, since your bandwidth most likely will be the bottle neck, it won't matter if you upload your data using 1 or 10 threads. Therefore it would make sense to process reports in Parallel and then queue them up somewhere else to upload. This should also make error handling easier (lost connection and such)

Comment: good thought. the reason i kept it within the same process is we do not update the database to a "completed" status until all files have been successfully uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think parallel foreach is nice, but it really sounds you can take advantage of your machine with TPL Dataflow.

You can get started here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx